# Expression to find all objects that contain all elements in an array of integers

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm struggling to return the right list of results with the queries outlined.  I'm trying to return a list of jobs to users(professionals) where the professional has all of the sectors specified in the job.  i.e. if the job has sector id's 6, 7 & 8, the professional must have skills 6, 7 & 8.

I've got the professionals sectors in a HashSet list and have tried unsuccessfully in a variety of ways to get my desired result.  Can anybody point out where I'm going wrong.

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = _context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == userId);

var professional = _context.Professionals
                           .Include(p => p.Positions)
                           .Include(p => p.Sectors)
                           .Single(p => p.Id == userId);

var positions = new HashSet<int>(professional.Positions.Select(c => c.Id));

var professionalSectors = new HashSet<int>(professional.Sectors.Select(c => c.Id));


var all = new HashSet<int>(_context.Sectors.Select(c => c.Id));

var proDoesNotHaveSectors = new HashSet<int>(all.Except(professional.Sectors.Select(c => c.Id)));

var feedQuery = from o in _context.Jobs
                from pos in o.Positions
                from sec in o.Sectors
                where positions.Contains(pos.Id) && !proDoesNotHaveSectors.Contains(sec.Id)
                select o;
```

I've also tried using the following query, which works if I'm just filtering from the page with nullable int[]? selectedSectors but not with Hashset or int[] array from database!!

```
var jobs = _context.Jobs
                   .Where(p => !professionalSectors.Select(t => t)  //Requires (t => t.Value) if int? [] array
                                                   .Except(p.Sectors.Select(t => t.Id))
                                                   .Any());
```

I've been going round in circles doing the same thing over again expecting different results, so hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: In Job class do you have positionID and sectorID?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev The job class has an ICollection of Positions and an ICollection of Sectors. Both are many to many relationships. Position has Id and Sector has Id. All of the right data is going in to the hashsets above. I just can't work out how to only return jobs where professional.Sectors contains all of the job.Sectors. returning where professional has Any of the job.Sectors same way as positions works fine, but not what I want!! I thought by checking if there were any of the job sectors in list of sectors professional didn't have that would be the same, but seems to return as any!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the explanation, looks like you are seeking for [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) method for `Sectors` (and [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Positions`):

```
var professional = ...;
var positions = ...;
var professionalSectors = ...;

var jobs = _context.Jobs
    .Where(job => job.Positions.Any(position => positions.Contains(position.Id))
        && job.Sectors.All(sector => professionalSectors.Contains(sector.Id)));
```

The only potential defect I see in the above query is that it will also include jobs without associated sectors (due to how `All` method works with empty sequence). Most likely it's not a real case (it might even be considered a feature - no skills required for the job), but if needed, just add the condition

```
&& job.Sectors.Any()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is doing the trick.  Appreciate your help.  Will save me going round in circles again tomorrow.  :)